# Debugger not moving to next line after input()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently learning python from invent with python!
I am on chapter 7 and here is the link to it!
https://inventwithpython.com/chapter7.html

I am doing the exercise Find the bug. I am having a problem at line answer = input() given in a line5:

```
import random
number1 = random.randint(1, 10)
number2 = random.randint(1, 10)
print('What is ' + str(number1) + ' + ' + str(number2) + '?')
answer = input()
if answer == number1 + number2:
    print('Correct!')
else:
    print('Nope! The answer is ' + str(number1 + number2))
```

I typed the number on the interactive screen but debugger doesn't moves to the next line. It stays on the above line. I thought I also need to press step bt new file opens.

Why isn't debugger moving to the next line when I type the number?

Comment: Did you press enter after you type the number?

Comment: Are you sure you performed the various operations in the right order ? You should **step** up to line 5. Then **step** again one time. Then, in your program console window **type the answer** and **press return**. Now the debugger _should_ have moved away from line 5. Could you confirm that in your case it still stays on the `input` line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your debugger at hand, so, I can't confirm that. But, as a wild guess, and assuming you performed the the various operations in the required order:

As of myself, I would *step over* (pressing the `over` button). Not *step into* (pressing the `step` button).

- *step into* will continue step by step execution *inside* the called function. If you call an other function it should show you the first line of the called function. And let you continue stepping. For a native function, I don't know how would behave your debugger.
- *step over* will continue execution at normal speed up to the next line of the currently examined source file. If you step over a function call, the function call is executed "normally", but execution stops once it returns.